# Get data from firebase: lateinit property currentUser has not been initialized

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to get data from Firebase and based on that information do something but before getting data my app crash.

I fetch data with this code:

```
private lateinit var currentUser: Student
database.collection("students").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid!!)
   get().addOnCompleteListener {
        currentUser = it.result!!.toObject(Student::class.java)!!
   }
```

and want to do this:

```
ex line 31: if(currentUser.group_a){
       // do some code
    } else {
       // do something else
    }
```

and I got this error: **lateinit property currentUser in line 31 has not been initialized**

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that the call to the database is asynchronous, and the initialization of your Student object will happen after the async work is done.

Here, you are trying to access `currentUser` before is initialized.

```
if(currentUser.group_a){
       // do some code
    } else {
       // do something else
    }
```

To solve your problem you can move that code inside your callback after initialization:

```
private lateinit var currentUser: Student
database.collection("students").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid!!)
   get().addOnCompleteListener {
        currentUser = it.result!!.toObject(Student::class.java)!!
        if(currentUser.group_a){
       // do some code
    } else {
       // do something else
    }
}
```

---

### Note

Make sure any access to the `currentUser` is done after you initialize, do not try to access it before because you will have the same issue. You can prevent the crash by initializing that Student object as null and checking for it before accessing its data.

### Tip

Make sure to treat your possible nulls, is not a good practice to assume that you will always receive non-null variables with `!!`, try using `let` on those objects to check them for null first.

Example:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid?.let { safeUserId ->
 database.collection("students").document(safeUserId)
   get().addOnCompleteListener {
        //I'm sure you can do the same for these ;)
        currentUser = it.result!!.toObject(Student::class.java)!!
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. I know that's work but my purpose is that I use coroutine for solving this problem.

Comment: then you will need to use .await() on the firebase request, you will need to import coroutines play services for it

Comment: Please read: https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-work-synchronously-with-firebase-coroutines-livedata-mvvm-clean-architecture-b2f72638ef61

Comment: The current question you asked do not have the word "coroutine on it" it says that you are having a problem with your variable, this answer solves your problem. You can mark this as correct and create a new one